# wxpython 3.0 & multiprocessing - update GUI from background process

Tags: python, wxpython, multiprocessing, publish-subscribe

From my wxpython GUI app I have an rsync task that I kick off as a multiprocessing.Process.

The idea is to update a wx.textCtrl with the constant output from this background process.

I am using a pubsub subscribe method.

The functions work fine but I can't get the textCtrl to update.

If I use a CallAfter method I get this crash/error:

> The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation
>   functionality safely. You MUST exec(). Break on
>   **THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC**()
>   to debug.

If I don't use that method and I try to append the text directly to the textctrl nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: try to generate custom events

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run wx commands from the remote process.  You could instead start and monitor rsync from a thread, then use PostEvent to add it to the event loop for textCtrl frame in the GUI thread.

Comment: Thanks Neapolitan I'll check out PostEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the child process can't write back to the main process. Use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to pass messages back to the main process, and update the control from within a timer or a background thread that waits for messages from the queue.